# Highcharts custom pattern fill shows different stroke width

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a custom pattern fill for highcharts.

It's a horizontal dashed line with alternating starting points from one row to another (the first start at 0,0 the second at 3,10 and so on).

I edited the [Highcharts JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/pattern-fill-pie) replacing the custom pattern with the following ([here you can find my "final" version](https://jsfiddle.net/uarqbtzn/)) :

```
color: {
    pattern: {
        path: {
            d: 'M 0 0 H 8 M 14 0 H 22 M 3 10 H 19',
            strokeWidth: 0.5
        },
        width: 22,
        height: 20
    }
}
```

The problem is the the two rows of lines have different width.
I can't find any parameter in the documentation to fix this.
I don't know if the problem is in my pattern definition or a highcharts bug.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the current code please ?

Comment: It's the code in the linked jsfiddle. I edited the question to make clear that it's my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path as-is moves first to `0,0` and then `14,0`, and finally `3,10`:

```
d: 'M 0 0 H 8 M 14 0 H 22 M 3 10 H 19'
```

You can change that to `0,1` and then `14,1`, and then `3,11` and the lines are the same width:

```
d: 'M 0 1 H 8 M 14 1 H 22 M 3 11 H 19'
```

The lines starting at `0,0` are centred on the boundary meaning that half the line gets cut off, so just moving them all down by 1 ensures that the whole line is visible.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/h72eumr0/)

Comment: thank you! I've read about this in another answer (for diagonal lines) but I didn't get it. Now its more clear!